# Adding a curve on DensityPlot: Epilog -> First[ContourPlot[...]] why the first?

Tags: plotting, data-types

I would like to understand why I have to add First around ContourPlot in the following example to have it working:

```
DensityPlot[LogTQ+LogA,{LogTQ,0,4},{LogA,0,4},PlotLegends->BarLegend[Automatic],ColorFunction->"SunsetColors",Epilog->First[ContourPlot[LogA==(LogTQ)^2,{LogTQ,0,4},{LogA,0,4}]]]
```

I looked at the documentation of ContourPlot which says: "ContourPlot returns Graphics[GraphicsComplex[data]]"

So I guess it means that as Epilog needs to take an object of the same type as First[ContourPlot] to work.

But I find it hard to understand it from the documentation.

**My questions:**

- In order to be more efficient with looking info on the documentation
  I would like some help to see where it is written. Indeed the only
  usefull info I found was that ContourPlot returns a Graphics. But
  where is it explained that Epilog should eat the first element of a
  Graphics. Furthermore what type is the first element of Graphics ?
- Also, for instance on the Epilog documentation is written:

  "is an option for graphics functions that gives a list of graphics
  primitives to be rendered after the main part of the graphics is
  rendered" This explain what Epilog returns, but not what it "eats". Does that actually means that Epilog must "eat" list of graphic primitives ?

Comment: There is in fact a documentation example of this needing `First` in an `Epilog` here https://wolfram.com/xid/0y8dpu-ek0xn . `Epilog` needs the primitives, not the `Graphics`.

Comment: @flinty Yes but imagine that you are trying to learn and stackexchange doesn't exist. How can you guess you have to do apply First. I mean it is a total guess in the fog. This link is in a sub section of the examples of Epilog. It is very hard to find.

Comment: My comment doesn't refer to stackexchange. That link points to an exact usage in the documentation. The documentation does a good job of spoon-feeding the answers with tutorials, neat-usages, applications etc. but  admittedly it's missing some details. For that stuff I would investigate using Mathematica itself, as it gives you all the reflective tools (`Head`, `Part`, etc.) to inspect expressions.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the documentation for [`Graphics`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html), you'll note that there is a list of all allowed primitives given, and that those primitives go into the first argument of `Graphics` (the rest is options). So if you have a graphics expression, the first element is a list of primitives, which is what `Epilog` wants. The only question now is what `ContourPlot` returns, and as you noted, `ContourPlot` is documented to return a graphics expression (which is technically not always the case when legends are added).

Combined this means: `Epilog` needs a list of graphics primitives, which are always in the first argument of a `Graphics` expression, and `ContourPlot` (as almost all plotting function) returns such an expression.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still have an issue (which probably deserves a new question I don't know). By reading Graphics documentation the way I would understand "primitives" is the first parameter to give to Graphics which I understand as a function. Not as the first element (in the sense [[1]]) of a "Graphics" list. Why do you interpret primitives in this page as the first element of Graphics and not as an input parameters it must take ? I am super confused by reading the documentation. Thanks !

Comment: In a way maybe I interpret Graphics as a function and not as something different conceptually (an object ?!). If it shouldn't be understood as a function I would like to see where it is explained (I don't see any conceptual difference between the doc of Graphics and ContourPlot for instance, if the latter should indeed be understood as a function and the first as something different "an object ?!").

Comment: `Graphics` is an inert wrapper (as indicated by the wording "represents a two-dimensional graphical image") - that means that `Graphics` isn't a function that evaluates to something else, it just stays like it is, and the frontend knows how to display them. If you look at the first example in "Properties & Relations" (the one with `InputForm`), you'll see that the underlying structure is still the same as what you input. So in this sense, `Graphics` is like another version of `List`, with the difference that it is displayed differently.

Comment: Allright so in general how can I make sure to understand properly the object I am looking for ? As soon as there is written "xxx represents something" it means it should not be understood as a function ? Is there a tutorial explaining those concepts with further details ?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not quite as consistently formulated in the documentation. Some indicators for inert objects: "represents, wrapper, formats as, ..." - in general, reading the documentation carefully and looking at the examples usually tells you whether a function is inert. Another option is to just look at whether it evaluates in a meaningful way (probably by using `InputForm` to make sure there's no formatting going on

Comment: Another thing to note is that by default, everything is an inert wrapper in Mathematica: If you e.g. write `f[x,y]` without defining `f`, it just stays unevaluated and can be used to indicate something when used in another function (if that function explicitly checks for the form of the argument)

Comment: Thanks. I asked a separate question on this here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/231119/how-to-know-if-a-built-in-expression-is-a-function-or-not I have some other questions related to your comment (in case you want to answer on the other topic). When you mean "inert wrapper" is it your way of calling the thing or a standard name (I typed inert wrapper mathematica on google but did not find anything). Also I didn't get what you mean with InputForm.