# How to know if a built-in expression is a function or not

Tags: functions, documentation

Following the comments on the answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/231102/adding-a-curve-on-densityplot-epilog-firstcontourplot-why-the-first/231104?noredirect=1#comment585947_231104) I would like to know if there is a way to deduce from the documentation if a built-in expression is a function or simply "a variable that stores something".

For the motivation you can look [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/231102/adding-a-curve-on-densityplot-epilog-firstcontourplot-why-the-first): without knowing if object are wrapper or not it would have been impossible for me to know that First[ContourPlot] gives the good variable to provide to Epilog for instance.

For instance, looking at the docs for [graphics](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html), it is not possible to understand that "primitives" and "options" are not parameter to provide to the function "Graphics" but actually what is stored in a Graphics type variable.

I find the documentation extremly confusing to learn, which is why I ask my question.

Thus, my question is precisely:

- Is there a way from the documentation to know if the expression is a function or a variable storing something
- If not, can I use some way in Mathematica to know it

Comment: _primitives_ and _options_ **are** parameters to the `Graphics` function which constructs the graphics. That's what the documentation is saying by writing it as `Graphics[primitives, options]`.  Usually the parameters are italicized and lowercase in the documentation, while the function names and directives start uppercased and are hyperlinked / blue. The `Graphics` doesn't _store_ anything. It's a function that takes a bunch of primitives, directives and options, and it takes that recipe to render the graphics.

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Comment: @flinty the "issue" is that `Graphics` is an inert wrapper and not so much a function (the rendering is technically also not really done by `Graphics` and more by `MakeBoxes`and the FE). If you look at the linked question, you can see that OP is asking how one can tell that a symbol is such an inert wrapper, and that it is therefore possible to extract the primitives simply by applying `First`.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi see the linked question for the context and motivation of this question

Comment: @LukasLang Yes you are right. So you use it like a function that doesn't evaluate but produces a side effect in the front-end? I guess that's never really bothered me and leaving out these details does not make the documentation _"extremely confusing to learn"_ but cleaner and focusing on the common-case. Is it enough just to check if the `Head` has not changed?

Comment: @flinty well how can you guess that First[ContourPlot] should be considered to give to Epilog then. Conceptually I don't see how I could have guessed that. And in my opinion a documentation should define things properly. Mathematica often uses vague wording in the documentation. This is fine as long as the exact meaning is written somewhere.

Comment: @flinty so in the end there is no way to know wether or not the tool I am using is a function or not ? I am not sure to understand what you mean by checking if the Head has changed. I would be interested to any method that would allow me to guess how it works.

Comment: @StarBucK it says in the documentation of `Epilog` that it needs primitives. If you do `Head[ContourPlot[...]]` you get a `Graphics`, so you need the first argument of that thing. That's a bit weird sure, but even without the documentation you could work that out by trying out `Head` on plots and things.

Comment: @flinty Allright. Maybe a stupid question but as english is not my mother tongue I don't know if this word is technical or just common language. By graphics "primitive" do we mean a very specific thing ? Or just a "Graphics" object ? And I am not sure to see your reasoning maybe because I am too bad in mathematica. Why would Head help me exactly if I figure out that it gives me a Graphics on ContourPlot ? If you want to write a detailed answer on that (again keeping in mind that I'm beginner) it would be for sure very helpfull !

Comment: @StarBucK It says in the documentation about `Epilog` it is expecting primitives. It says in the documentation for things like `Polygon` and `Line` (expand the details and options section) that _xxx can be used as a geometric region or a graphics primitive._ If you do `x = ContourPlot[...]; Head[x]` you get a `Graphics`. So you know `x` is a graphics and the form of `Graphics` is `Graphics[primitives, options]`, so you know the `First` argument is a list of primitives. If a function `f` is like a wrapper thing, then its `Head` doesn't change when the function is used, e.g `Head[f[2]] === f`

Comment: ... and `Head[Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}]]` is still a `Graphics`. By the way, if you want a list of primitives, expand the _details and options_ section in the `Graphics` documentation where it says _The following graphics primitives can be used:..._ . Primitives are things like `Arrow`, `AASTriangle`, `Disk`, `BezierCurve`  etc...

Comment: @flinty allright I think I see what you mean then ! Thanks.